# How to namespace routes in Rails 4 to set up Forem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, forem

I've been trying to set up Forem (a Rails 4 forum engine) using a [guide](http://www.sitepoint.com/forem-rails-forum-engine/) and [original docs](https://github.com/rubysherpas/forem).

Most things work, but I'm getting route errors.  In my application.erb I have this route in a link_to:

```
topic_path(u)
```

The guide recommends that I preface this with my application name so my routes won't conflict with Forem's routes, so I did that as so:

```
H2le.topic_path(u)
```

(H2le is the application name set in application.rb)

However, this errors out:

> "undefined method `topic_path' for H2le:Module"

Am I not setting the application name properly?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my being a Ruby newb and the [guide](http://www.sitepoint.com/forem-rails-forum-engine/) I was following perhaps not being super explicit.  It recommended to namespace the links like:

`main_app.path`

And I interpreted `main_app` to be a placeholder for my app name.  Well, wrong.  `main_app` is a built-in helper function, so it should literally just say `main_app`.  I fixed this, and everything worked.